# Is there a way to avoid redundant "using" directives when I only want to use an alias some of the time?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I've been writing a lot of code that works with Windows Forms and Excel Interop recently. One of the things that I've encountered is ambiguous references. For example, if I try to create a new Excel application, it doesn't work.

```
Application app = new Application { Visible = true };
```

This line returns an error because the reference to Application is ambiguous.  It could refer to an Excel application, but it could also refer to a Windows Forms application.

Instead of typing this out:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { Visible = true };
```

I know I can just change my using directive to this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

and then change my declaration of app to:

```
Excel.App app = new Excel.App { Visible = true};
```

However, later on in my code, I have to declare quite a few worksheets and workbooks. Without using the "Excel = Microsoft..." namespace alias, I could just do this since the references to Workbook and Worksheet aren't ambiguous:

```
Workbook someWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet someWorksheet = app.ActiveSheet;
```

But when I change my using directive to

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I have to change  all declarations that use Excel objects to "Excel.someObject", or I have to add a second using directive:

**Option 1:**

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
Excel.Application app = new Application { Visible = true };
Excel.Workbook someWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet someWorkSheet = app.ActiveSheet;
```

**Option 2:**

```
using Excel = Microsoft.OFfice.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
...
Excel.Application app = new Application { Visible = true };
Workbook someWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet someWorkSheet = app.ActiveSheet;
```

---

I much prefer Option 2, and this is me being pedantic, but the redundancy of having to write two using directives to refer to the same library is irksome. **Is there a third option that allows me to write my declarations as seen in option 2 without having to use two using directives? That is, is there a way to write my using directive such that the alias can be used where needed but omitted where references aren't ambiguous?**

Comment: You already know all of the possibilities. I'd use option 2, i don't find it irksome.

Comment: `using` *directives*. `using` statements are blocks that call `Dispose` for you automatically. It's unfortunate that there are two completely different features with the similar names, but there it is. So it's helpful to use the *correct* name for the feature you're using, rather than the name of the other one.

Comment: My bad. I'll make the edit.

Comment: I believe these are the only possibilities. My preference would be option 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a file that does not need to refer to `System.Windows.Forms.Application` (most files in your project should be like that), add `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` at the namespace level:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestForms {

    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    class TestClass {
        Application app = ... // This refers to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    }

}
```

This way `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` would "win" over `System.Windows.Forms.Application` for all classes that follow `using` declaration.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for because it works for my case, but I also appreciate Habib's answer because it helps me avoid getting myself into this situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a third option that allows me to write my declarations as
>   seen in option 2 without having to use two using statements?

No. There is not. Your best bet is to use option 2.

[`using` **directive**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) usage for alias support is useful for specifying alias for a type or namespace.

You should look into Resharper, which could help you do the cleanup better than Visual Studio.

This problem can also be solved with a better design. Try to keep your work related to Excel in a separate class/modules, so that you can avoid conflicting namespaces issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind when writing future code.

Comment: I do agree that option 2 is better. It's one more line of code up top vs. prefacing every Workbook/sheet declaration with "Excel."